# drag and drop drawings angular4

Tags: html, angular, html5-canvas

I need to build an angular app in which i will be given with a photo in a canvas and i have to put some objects on it from given list using drag and drop and resize them and in the end save it as an image. i am not much familiar with html, only aware that we can play with this sort of stuff using canvas.

i have tried to search all around but all i have found is drag and drop functionality of lists and files, not images.

Just looking for a direction, any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I am working in angular4.